# Maven and POI: package error and to compile the code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, package, apache-poi

I have the following code:

```
    import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;



public class CreateWorkBook 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
   {
      //Create Blank workbook
      HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
      //Create file system using specific name
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("createworkbook.xlsx"));
      //write operation workbook using file out object 
      workbook.write(out);
      out.close();
      System.out.println("createworkbook.xlsx written successfully");
   }
}
```

but the Eclipse environment complains for line:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
```

it said:

> - HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type

I have the package correctly loaded: import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

For more information, the pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.x.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>ExcelPass</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ExcelPass</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>
```

Why it's asking for that? What's wrong in my configuration?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try running the command `mvn clean install` from a command prompt and check if you get the same error. If not then there is something wrong with your eclipse. On eclipse, try updating your project by `Right Click on the project -> Maven -> Update`

Comment: @RITZXAVI: `mvn clean install` is ok: 

BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.085 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-30T18:35:14+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/124M

I'm trying to find your second suggestion, but updated it don't change nothing.

Comment: So that means there is something wrong with your eclipse. Did you try deleting the project from eclipse and re-importing it again?

Comment: Yes of course, I'll let you know later.

Comment: @RITZXAVI: Hi, now I have fix the problem and I don't have red underline on my code, but I have a warning:
Resource leak: 'workbook' is never closed regards the line 
`HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();` and after if I try to compile as Java Application, the file doesn't run.

Comment: @RITZXAVI: that's right I have fix the problem of compilation, it was to configure 'Run as'.
Thank you for the first part of the problem, following your advice I have recreated all the project from the start.

Comment: Thank you. I have added my comment as an answer. Feel free to mark it as an answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the project from `Eclipse` and then re-importing it again.
This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Summarise, the following passage we need to check:

1) have you added the Apache POI dependency to the Maven POM? e.g.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

2) have you run a Maven build from the command line to make sure it completes successfully? e.g.

```
$ mvn clean package
```

3) When you run a Maven build it downloads all required dependencies, and install them into the local Maven repository, as configured in $MAVEN_HOME/config/settings.xml. You should find the POI libraries (JAR) files in your local Maven repo e.g.

```
poi-3.7.jar
```

If you open this archive with 7-Zip or by running the JDK jar utility, you will see that it contains the class Eclipse cannot find.

4) Have you imported the project in Eclipse as a Maven project with File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects?

5) When you expand the Eclipse project "Java Resources" -> "Libraries" do you see a library called "Maven Dependencies"? When you expand it do you see the POI JAR file listed?

[image]